# Remove special characters from string SQL after character

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, special-characters

My current data set has a value that is acceptablevalue_5cjunk data.  The data that I want to remove using SQL is the string that starts with _5c.

I have tried using a replace statement with a like function which does not work.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('mytable') IS NOT NULL drop table mytable
CREATE TABLE mytable
    ([mycol] varchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO mytable
    ([mycol])
VALUES
    ('97W'),
    ('125_5c0a9abac73d4'),
    ('121_5c0a9abac73d4'),
    ('121_5c0a9abac73d4'),
    ('123_5c0a9abac73d4'),
    ('112H'),
    ('111H')
;


SELECT REPLACE([mycol],like'_5c%','')
from mytable
```

What I would like to see is:

```
97W
125
121
121
123
112H
111H
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no function that will replace after a certain pattern is matched, however, since you only want to remove the characters, replace is not necessary at all, you can just use [`LEFT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to strip out the characters before the pattern (using [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to find the pattern),along with a case expression to make sure you account for scenarios where the pattern is not found:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_5c', MyCol) = 0 THEN MyCol 
            ELSE LEFT(MyCol, CHARINDEX('_5c', MyCol) - 1) 
        END
FROM mytable;
```